# Makefile make install not executing multiple line commands

Tags: shell, environment-variables, make

I have a Makefile that contains an `install` section to allow me to `make install` after building the source code. The `install` section contains two lines of shell commands:

```
install: /usr/local/lib
    cp $(LIB_OBJ) $<
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$<
```

So the first line copies the libxxx.so to `/usr/local/lib` and the second line sets the environmental variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib` so that final executable can find the libxxx.so file.

But when I run `make install` from the command line and then type:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It shows empty content rather than `/usr/local/lib` as intended. So why is the second line of command in the Makefile not executed?

Answer (score 3):

`make` is almost certainly executing both lines of commands. However, the line `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$<` (or whatever `make` expands it) gets executed by a shell that's a child process of the `make` process. When you type `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you get whatever the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH had in it. Your shell didn't execute the "export", a sub-process of `make` executed it. You'll have to do the export in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever file, or type it in manually.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way to put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` in Makefile so that when user type `make install`, all libraries built will be in the path? If I export it in `.bashrc`, it will be permanently set. So I don't want to do that. If I need to manually export it, then `make install` is not automatic.

Comment: There might be some weird trick.  After all you can re-TTY a process with "reptyr" (https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr). There's probably some `gdb` stunt you could do to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I don't think you should do those stunts on a regular basis.

Comment: So what is the rationale that the multiline command is executed by a sub-process of make, instead of by the make process itself? Is this designed intentionally in make utility?

Comment: I don't think the distinction is multiline vs single line, I think it's if the command(s) contain a shell metacharacter (>, &, ;, etc) then `make` shells out rather than just forking and execing. The rationale here is probably, "it's really hard to parse shell command lines correctly, let's just hand all the hard work off to the shell."

Comment: Actually, it's not even a shell metacharacter. Most `make`s will create a subshell for each line that begins with a tab character. The `export` is taken as a shell command, not as a `make` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH := /usr/local/lib:$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

install:
#Do Install actions
```

See [Section 5.3 of the Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution) for an explanation of Bruce's correct assumption on subshells, whivh leads us to [this Answer at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941110/how-i-could-add-dir-to-path-in-makefile), which states that all commands should be executed as a one liner.

### Update

Since the one liner did not work, use the following, as an example (I'm including the files below so that the final makefile will Work):
**Filelist**:
**hellomacke.c**

```
#include 

int main() {
  // call a function in another file
  myPrintHelloMake();

  return(0);
}
```

**hellofunc.c**

```
#include 
#include 

void myPrintHelloMake(void) {

  printf("Hello makefiles!\n");

  return;
}
```

**hellomake.h**

```
/*
example include file
*/

void myPrintHelloMake(void);
```

**End Filelist**

---

**Makefile**

```
IDIR =../include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = hellomake.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

---

The above makefile uses Macros and String Expansion to properly set the include and libraries directories without the need of the `export` command.  In your case, passing `/usr/local/libs` to `LDIR` and then compiling should get you started.

---

### References

[Colby College, Maine, Computer Science Department - Makefile Tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)
[The M4 Macro Processor -  Paste Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4-1.4.15/html_node/Patsubst.html)

Comment: I put the export command before install but it didn't work. I even put the two commands in one line but not working either.

Comment: Are you "piping" `LIB_OBJ` into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?  I've never seen `$<` as in your OP.

Comment: No, `$<` is just an automatic variable used by Makefile to denote the first argument in the rule, which is /usr/local/lib.